# How do I search with / command in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can search with / command in VSCode just like vim?
I have installed VIM extension and a bunch of extensions that may simulate vim. But I can only do these:

```
dd - delete line
gg - go to top of the file
G  - go to the bottom
```

I can't do these:

```
/  - search
:  - do set or other commands like %s/../../g (no ":" mode at all)
.  - repeat last action
0  - go to the beginning of the line
ZZ - save and exit
```

Looks like the Vim extensions have not carry over all vim neat shortcuts.
What do I need to add in settings?

I like a lot of vim features, would like to have them all in VSCode if possible.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact all the features you mentioned is well implemented. But different extensions can cause conflictions, especially when they all tend to change the shortcuts, which probably result in unpredictable behaviors. You'd better try to disable all other extensions that simulate vim but Vim provided by vscodevim. If the problem still there, reset the Vim setting, or reinstall it.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Conflicts are caused by other extensions. (don't know which one) So I uninstalled all other vim related extensions. Exit & restart vscode. It works like a charm again. Thank you very much!